# Comprobar ficheros borrados en origen con XCOPY

Tags: cmd, batch

Tengo un proceso `bat` en el trabajo para copiar las modificaciones que he hecho durante el día en mi carpeta personal al servidor. Utilizo `XCOPY`para ello de la siguiente forma:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO =============================================
ECHO Copia de ficheros a la carpeta de OneDrive
ECHO =============================================
@ECHO.
ECHO Si hay ficheros nuevos o modificados, se copiaran a continuacion... En caso de no haberlos, no se realizaran cambios
ECHO --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XCOPY  C:\Users\pablo.delgado.flores\Documents\Pablo_Delgado\* "C:\Users\pablo.delgado.flores\OneDrive - PDelgado" /E /D /C /Y
@ECHO.
ECHO Proceso terminado correctamente
PAUSE
```

Ahora me gustaría mejorarlo para que cuando elimine ficheros en la carpeta local, también lo borre en el destino. He estado mirando parámetros de `XCOPY` pero no he encontrado ninguno relacionado con el borrado. Mirando alternativas, he encontrado `ROBOCOPY` con `/purge` así:

```
ROBOCOPY C:\Users\pablo.delgado.flores\Documents\Pablo_Delgado\* "C:\Users\pablo.delgado.flores\OneDrive - PDelgado" /purge /V
```

Pero no consigo hacerlo. ¿Hay alguna manera?

Comment: ¿Que problema tienes con `robocopy`? prueba usar la opción `/mir`

Comment: Ya he probado la opción `/mir` @PatricioMoracho, pero no se acerca a lo que busco. He corregido el error de mi código, le sobraba el `*` en el origen, pero ahora me muestra el mensaje de que no puede borrar un fichero de tipo `849C9593-D756-4E56-8D6E-42412F2A707B` porque está siendo usado por otro programa. ¿Hay forma de eliminar ese mensaje?

Comment: Quiere la opción /mov (o /move si queire que borren las carpetas tambien)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no es necesario usar el flag `*` puedes hacerlo asi:

```
ROBOCOPY -E -PURGE C:\Users\pablo.delgado.flores\Documents\Pablo_Delgado\ "C:\Users\pablo.delgado.flores\OneDrive - PDelgado"
```

que segun la misma documentacion de robocopy `robocopy /?` ( -MIR equivalent a /E mas /PURGE):

- /E copiar subdirectorios
- /PURGE eliminar en el destino si no existe en el origen

ejemplo con /MIR:

```
robocopy -MIR C:\Users\pablo.delgado.flores\Documents\Pablo_Delgado\ "C:\Users\pablo.delgado.flores\OneDrive - PDelgado"
```